# mailx not sending mail if contents include "backup.sh"

Tags: linux, email, redhat

I have a very strange problem with mailx. I will describe the problem quickly and will then give environment details.

I have a file `/tmp/junk`. I try to mail the contents of this file to me as follows:

```
ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: cat junk |  mailx -s "some subject" myemail@mydomain.com
```

If the file `/tmp/junk` has a word '**backup.sh**', then I don't get the mail. If the file doesn't have the word '**backup.sh**', I do get the mail.

Example:
If the file contents are as follows:

```
ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: cat junk
a for archive archive.sh
b for backup backup.sh
c for configure configure.sh
```

I **wouldn't** get the mail

But if the second line says anything other than `backup.sh` (e.g. `backup1.sh` or `back.sh` or `backup.shh` or `backup_sh`), then I **do** get the mail. The word `backup.sh` doesn't need to be at the specific place shown. If that word is there anywhere in the file, I wouldn't get the mail.

I checked that the mail has not bounced to the sender. I checked the `/var/log/messages`, but don't see anything relevant there. I don't know if I should be checking any other log files.

I am totally puzzled. Can someone help?

**Environment details:**

```
ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: which mailx
/bin/mailx

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: ls -l /bin/mailx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 27  2014 /bin/mailx -> mail

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: ls -l /bin/mail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root mail 84856 Jul 13  2006 /bin/mail

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: file /bin/mail
/bin/mail: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: uname -a
Linux ott01pslpr0001 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 5 21:21:44 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp: cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)

ott01pslpr0001(oracle:NONE):/tmp:
```

Thanks in advance ...

-- Parag

Comment: You want to check the `/var/log/maillog*` logs of the server on which you execute `mailx` if the message gets sent or not, and if it does you need to check the incoming mailserver that handles `@mydomain.com` to see if your message doesn't get discarded by a spam filter or anti-virus.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked `/var/log/maillog`. In both cases (when I got the mail and when I didn't), the messages in the maillog were exactly same (except for timestamp and message ids).

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out something. We use outlook365. Typically the spam goes to a folder called "Clutter" and I had checked for the missing messages there, without any luck. But I found out that there is another folder called "Junk Email" (I need to figure out what is the difference between the two) and I found this message there. So, somehow the word "backup.sh" is triggering some junk email rule on outlook365. I should have seen this folder earlier. My oversight. Sorry about that.